# MongoSourceConnector tombstone didnt work

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I want make a CQRS with data mesh, and i already success to create **MongoSourceConnector** and **ElasticsearchSinkConnector**, but im confuse why my **MongoSourceConnector** configuration didn't publish null message when document in mongodb got deleted

This is my configuration **MongoSourceConnector**

```
{
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "publish.full.document.only.tombstone.on.delete": "true",
    "output.format.value": "schema",
    "output.schema.value": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ais-user.administrator\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"emailIsVerified\",\"type\":\"boolean\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"role\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"createdBy\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"createdBy\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"userId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}},{\"name\":\"createdAt\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"updatedAt\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "output.format.key": "schema",
    "output.schema.key": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"keySchema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "transforms": "ExtractFieldKeyID,RenameFieldValueID",
    "transforms.ExtractFieldKeyID.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.ExtractFieldKeyID.field": "documentKey._id",
    "transforms.RenameFieldValueID.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.RenameFieldValueID.renames": "_id:id",
    "database": "ais-user",
    "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
    "connection.uri": "",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "ais-user.administrator",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}
```

I already try to set **publish.full.document.only = false** and **output.format.value = json**, and i got value of published like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_data": "82643E07580000000C2B022C0100296E5A100431083771BA4B4BCFBBF24694299DECD346645F69640064643E071BE67743D512CDF2380004"
  },
  "operationType": "delete",
  "clusterTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1681786712,
      "i": 12
    }
  },
  "wallTime": "2023-04-18T02:58:32.348Z",
  "ns": {
    "db": "ais-user",
    "coll": "administrator"
  },
  "documentKey": {
    "_id": "643e071be67743d512cdf238"
  }
}
```

As you can see, delete operation can publish a value, but why if set **publish.full.document.only = true**, its didnt, i want if there a deleted document in mongo, kafka willl publish null values

Comment: Removed Debezium tag since you're not using it.. But you could try it instead, which will publish tombstone if you configure it to

Comment: Thank for the advice, but i want try with mongodb source connector

Comment: That's fine. [Try the other one](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.1/connectors/mongodb.html) and compare the difference

Comment: were you able to figure this out? even I am looking for the same. thank you